# How to choose $x$ according to a pdf that looks like $1-\exp(-x)$ when I can't evaluate the cdf

Tags: statistics, random

I have the pdf of a random variable $x$ and it looks like $1-\exp(-x)$.
I want to find a way to construct a method that picks random $x$ according to this distribution.
Let's say by using another variable that has a uniform distribution.
I tried doing so by calculating the CDF but this is unsolvable from what I understand.

The CLT method would look like:
$t=\int_{0}^{x}{1−\exp(−x')}dx'=x+\exp(−x)−1$ when always $x>0$ and we solve for the uniformly distributed variable $t$. It turns out the solution is called the lambert $W$ function. But the solution is sometimes complex for some values of t. So I guess I don't have a real valued solution everywhere? Is there a workaround to solve this?

Notice that this isn't a regular exponential distribution otherwise it would have been simple. What would be a suggestion for a workaround?

Thanks.

Comment: what's the support of your distribution?

Comment: I think you must have meant that the **CDF** is $F(x) =1-e^{-x},$ for $x>0.$ [It clearly can't be a density function.] This is the CDF of $X\sim\mathsf{Exp}(1).$ Let $u=F(x).$ Then the quantile function (inverse CDF) is $x = F^{-1}(u) = -\ln(1-u),$ as in @Tommik's now deleted Answer. If `u` is a vector of 1000 simulated realizations of $\mathsf{Unif}(0,1),$ R code `-log(1-u)` will return 1000 simulated realizations of $\mathsf{Exp}(1).$

Comment: Thank you but no. This is my pdf. I realize it is very similar to the CDF of an exponential distribution but it a pdf. That's why i'm having a difficulty...

Comment: The support for the distribution is from a system i'm studying. The time a particle in my system is trapped until it escapes goes according to this pdf. I want to draw a number according to this pdf and say that the particle was trapped for that amount of time. I need it as a part of a bigger simulation.

Comment: $1-\exp(-x)$ can't be a pdf (even suitably normalized) because it isn't integrable

Comment: what do you mean? the integral is x+exp(-x).

Comment: for $1-\exp(-x)$ to be a pdf the support should be something like $x\in (0,1.8414\cdots)$?

Comment: What I mean is that the probability for x goes to a constant as time goes to infinity. and it goes there in exponential manner. I found the solution for the CDF method in this case, meaning $t=\int{1-exp(-x)}dt=x+exp(-x)-1$ when always $x<0$ and we solve for the uniformly distributed variable $t$ is called the lambert W function. But the solution is sometimes complex. So I guess I don't have a real valued solution everywhere?

Comment: $x>0$ always. typo